# how to transform nested JSON object into rows and columns in Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, nested

I have a json file and pretty new to json and pandas. How can I flatten this JSON based on the conversation id or csv data.

Json data here : https://pastebin.pl/view/64022f08

```
import json
import pandas as pd
with open('/Users/rp/Downloads/apires.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
df1 = pd.json_normalize(data)
print(df1)
```

Can someone help on this. unable to figure for two days.

Comment: Can u add ur file here please, or example like ur file. and also an example of the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ritu Patil

Your **.json** is **json-dictionary** (key, value):

So for accessing to proper element in dictionary You need to access those like this:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
data = json.load(open('test.json'))

dfMetadata = pd.DataFrame(data['_metadata'])
dfData =pd.DataFrame(data['conversationHistoryRecords'])
```

---

It's transform this dataset into two dataframes from .json.

[image]

For getting the proper key, which interest You:
In this structure there is posibility to check between corelations, and researching this dataset.

Also there is option to access to specific row in this line:

```
conversationHistoryRecords = data['conversationHistoryRecords']
campaign = conversationHistoryRecords[0]['campaign']
```

where **campaign** is variable for data worth to explore(in this case):

```
{'campaignEngagementId': '2330596212',
 'campaignEngagementName': 'Engagement-123',
 'campaignId': '2266771712',
 'campaignName': 'Live_Chat_on_your_site',
 'goalId': '2266719412',
 'goalName': 'Interact with visitors',
 'engagementAgentNote': 'agent-note-test-messaging',
 'engagementSource': 'WEB_SITE',
 'visitorBehaviorId': '2379540212',
 'visitorBehaviorName': 'someVisitorBehavior',
 'engagementApplicationId': '28879660-84fd-4cd8-a1d7-ba3247bdb252',
 'engagementApplicationName': 'Some Mobile App Test',
 'engagementApplicationTypeId': '92274cfd-29e7-4d94-a013-0646212d8075',
 'engagementApplicationTypeName': 'Mobile App',
 'visitorProfileId': '2286779312',
 'visitorProfileName': 'All visitors',
 'lobId': 2389848512,
 'lobName': 'lob_123',
 'locationId': '2266779612',
 'locationName': 'Entire site',
 'profileSystemDefault': True,
 'behaviorSystemDefault': False}
```

Comment: Thanks. But looks like it is not parsing as exactly you shown in the picture. Is the code complete?

Comment: @RituPatil - edited - there was need to assign to conversationHistoryRecords like this: conversationHistoryRecords = data['conversationHistoryRecords']

Comment: Your concept about groupBy conversationId - isn't concise - cause there is only 1 conversationId per whole .json.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. wil check. I Will read further on this case. do you have any specific documents to read for my case?

Comment: just precise - which needed for bussiness requirements and how to check correlation and valuable conclusions.